# unmarshal a xml string with jaxb

Tags: jaxb, jaxb2-basics

I have a string to unmarshal

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Nbr>65</Nbr>
```

i want to get the value 65.

please help me , i am beginner in JAXB.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at unmarshalling examples available over internet. One such example: http://www.javatpoint.com/jaxb-unmarshalling-example